# How do I prevent a flexbox from becoming wider when it contains a text input field?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The following CSS/HTML gives me my desired result - three boxes on a row, the middle one has a fixed width and the outer ones consume (in equal quantity) the space on either side:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
}
#container > * {
  background: #efefef;
}
#container .fixed-width-40px {
  width: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.fill-available-horizontal-space {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
<div id="container">
    <div class="fill-available-horizontal-space">aaa</div>
    <div class="fixed-width-40px">bbb</div>
    <div class="fill-available-horizontal-space">ccc</div>
</div>
```

However, if I add a form (and text input field within it) to the third box, the third box becomes wider and the first box becomes shorter.

I want the first and third boxes to retain equal width, but the introducton of the text input field is ruining this.

Please do you know how I can overcome this?

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="fill-available-horizontal-space">aaa</div>
    <div class="fixed-width-40px">bbb</div>
    <div class="fill-available-horizontal-space">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="test"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is "flex-grow: 1;" in the childs you want filling the available space.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
}
#container > * {
  background: #efefef;
}
#container .fixed-width-40px {
  width: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.fill-available-horizontal-space {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 50%;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="fill-available-horizontal-space"></div>
    <div class="fixed-width-40px">bbb</div>
    <div class="fill-available-horizontal-space"><input></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why my post was associated to one that doesn't address the problem I was having, I had already linked to the duplicate because I was looking for the Flexbox version of the fix. Anyway, thank you alotropico for the fix, I had already tried that but it wasn't working because I have a form and a single text input in the third box and it's making the third box wider than the first. I wrote this question without realising that forms within divs would make flexboxes wider.

Comment: TBH the issue was answered using flexbox in that question, in the second and third most voted answers, which are newer than the accepted one. The thing with flex is that it usually doesn't leave you with exact numbers but rather useful flexible approximations, in this case if you want a specific child's grow to take precedence you can play incrementing it's flex-grow value. Cheers

Comment: I played and it didn't, so my last resort was to duplicate the contents of the third box to the first, then make the contents of the first box visibility: hidden. Dirty, yes. If I get time I'll play some more.

Comment: I edited my answer, if you give 50% width to the expanding divs they should have the same size, whatever theit content is

Comment: If I could accept your answer a second time I would, but instead could only give it an up vote. thanks buddy :)